# How to find the certificate added with SecItemAdd in Keychain

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, certificate

Following [apple's doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/certificates/storing_a_certificate_in_the_keychain), I wrote this code to add a certificate to my login keychain on macOS

```
let certUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "cert", withExtension: "cer")!
let certData = try! Data(contentsOf: certUrl)
let cert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(nil, certData as CFData)!
let addQuery: [String: Any] = [
    kSecClass as String: kSecClassCertificate,
    kSecValueRef as String: cert,
    kSecAttrLabel as String: "My Certificate"
]
let status = SecItemAdd(addQuery as CFDictionary, nil)
guard status == errSecSuccess else {
    print(status)
    return true
}
print("cert added")
return true
```

It works, but the problem is that when I opened the Keychain Access app, I couldn't find the added certificate in login keychain's certificate category.

I tried running the code again, and it failed with duplicate certificate error. So the certificate must have been added. I wonder how to find it in Keychain Access? Or certificates added using SecItemAdd are always hidden from the Keychain Access app?

macOS version: 10.15.1

Answer (score 0):

I was using Mac Catalyst. Switching to a cocoa app made it work.

Comment: It seems that Mac Catalyst can't access the certificates, did you get it without macOS cocoa?